# Unable to Register user in UserGrid: All Host Pools Marked Down. Retry burden pushed out to client

Tags: tomcat, cassandra, usergrid

Here is a image of the error I am getting shown on the right top corner.

[Click Here too see the error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbZmv.png)

I followed the documentation here https://usergrid.readthedocs.org/en/two-dot-o-instructions/deploy-local.html step by step.

Cassandra nodetool status is Up and Normal.

I have added the **usergrid-deployment.properties** & **usergrid-custom.properties** in the tomcat/lib directory.

I have done the database setup by running this: /system/database/setup

Here is the output:

**{
  "action" : "cassandra setup",
  "status" : "ok",
  "timestamp" : 1455528923575,
  "duration" : 0
}**

Also i Have done the superuser setup: /system/superuser/setup

Here is the output:

**{
  "action" : "superuser setup",
  "status" : "ok",
  "timestamp" : 1455528985483,
  "duration" : 1
}**

But when I run  /localhost:8080/status/ I get the following output:

```
    {
      "timestamp" : 1455529162925,
      "duration" : 25,
      "status" : {
      "started" : 1455525966458,
      "uptime" : 3196467,
      "version" : "0.0.29-SNAPSHOT",
      "cassandraAvailable" : false,
      "org.apache.usergrid.count.AbstractBatcher" : {
      "add_invocation" : {
           "type" : "timer",
           "unit" : "microseconds",
           "duration" : {
           "min" : 0.0,
           "max" : 0.0,
           "mean" : 0.0,
           "std_dev" : 0.0,
           "median" : 0.0,
           "p75" : 0.0,
           "p95" : 0.0,
           "p98" : 0.0,
           "p99" : 0.0,
           "p999" : 0.0
           },
    "rate" : {
      "unit" : "seconds",
      "count" : 0,
      "mean" : 0.0,
      "m1" : 0.0,
      "m5" : 0.0,
      "m15" : 0.0
    }
  },
  "batch_add_invocations" : {
    "type" : "counter",
    "count" : 0
  },
  "counter_existed" : {
    "type" : "counter",
    "count" : 0
  }
},
"org.apache.usergrid.count.CassandraSubmitter" : {
  "submit_invocation" : {
    "type" : "timer",
    "unit" : "microseconds",
    "duration" : {
      "min" : 0.0,
      "max" : 0.0,
      "mean" : 0.0,
      "std_dev" : 0.0,
      "median" : 0.0,
      "p75" : 0.0,
      "p95" : 0.0,
      "p98" : 0.0,
      "p99" : 0.0,
      "p999" : 0.0
    },
    "rate" : {
      "unit" : "seconds",
      "count" : 0,
      "mean" : 0.0,
      "m1" : 0.0,
      "m5" : 0.0,
      "m15" : 0.0
    }
  }
},
"org.apache.usergrid.rest.filters.MeteringFilter" : {
  "activeRequests" : {
    "type" : "counter",
    "count" : 1
  },
  "requests" : {
    "type" : "timer",
    "unit" : "milliseconds",
    "duration" : {
      "min" : 1.808735,
      "max" : 1259.105594,
      "mean" : 251.21387366666664,
      "std_dev" : 431.53739723624284,
      "median" : 7.695549,
      "p75" : 486.10919975,
      "p95" : 1259.105594,
      "p98" : 1259.105594,
      "p99" : 1259.105594,
      "p999" : 1259.105594
    },
    "rate" : {
      "unit" : "seconds",
      "count" : 12,
      "mean" : 0.003754176303820466,
      "m1" : 0.001183680264329619,
      "m5" : 0.00355060808920887,
      "m15" : 0.0033384011532465838
    }
  }
}
    }
    }
```

Here I can clearly see
**"cassandraAvailable" : false**

I am using:
Tomcat 8
Cassandra 3.3
Elastic Search 1.7.2
Java 8
Ubuntu 14.04

Please help me. I have been trying this for days. I have gone through the other questions asked too but none seem to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are using out of date docs and an old/unsupported version of Usergrid.

The official Usergrid docs are here:

http://usergrid.apache.org/docs/

Deployment Guide is here:

http://usergrid.apache.org/docs/installation/deployment-guide.html

The best Usergrid version to start with is doing to be Usergrid 2.1, which will be released in a couple of days. You can get the Usergrid 2.1 release candidate now, read this email:

https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/usergrid-dev/201602.mbox/%3cCAF1aazA8zJ9=pU5crZnn1bEtb7aHLKF5L_Bq5fy7FM3u_k70CA@mail.gmail.com%3e

Comment: Thank you for the links @snoopdave. I'll get back to you once I am done reading the docs and installing it again.

Comment: I too having the same issue that cassandra is unavailable. Can you help me  how to resolve it?